# Vertically align text on the right of the image

Tags: css, html, css-float, vertical-alignment

There are many examples of vertically aligned text on the left of the image, but these same examples do not work if I attempt to place the text on the right side of the image.

On working example for the text on the left of the image is this: http://jsfiddle.net/rVTcv/

HTML:

```
<div style="height:259px;" class="how-right">
    <img src="img/how-it-works/num-1.PNG" width="267px" height="259px">
    <span>JivaWay has a simple system to get you in shape in just 6 weeks.  And it's so easy to follow, even people who have never exercised before can do it.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.how-right img {
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
span {
    height: 259px;            
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If I attempt to move the text on the right by **moving** the `float:right` property of the image to the text, then I don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approaching it wrong, simply float the image to the left and update the margin to the right side instead

http://jsfiddle.net/rVTcv/140/

```
.how-right img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align :middle;
}
```